# How to implement ServletContextListener in servlet accessed through Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I am got a requirement where i need to call the contextInitialized and contextDestroyed method of ServletContextListener that is hit from the jsp page..According to my need i have to use some timer input parameters that is recieved from Jsp page but i am not able to achive this ...

I have created a servet but this servlet is not as per the requirement so request is not going from jsp form to servlet and i have know idea what to add in the servlet to get the hit and inputs from jsp page..

Here is my Servlet page..

```
@WebListener()
public class MyContext implements ServletContextListener {

//private ScheduledExecutorService sched;
Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    //sched = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    //sched.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(
            //Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.TUESDAY);
            Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 00);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    timer.schedule(
            new MyTask(),
            date.getTime(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    //sched.shutdownNow();
    timer.cancel();
}
```

}

and here is my jsp page..

```
 <form action="MyContext" method="GET">
        <label>Set Date: </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Set Time: </label>
        <input type="text" name="time" id="time">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
    </form>
```

and here is my web.xml file ..

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyContext</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyContext</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyContext</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyContext</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listner>
    <listner-class>
 MyContext
    </listner-class>>
</listner>>
```

Please guys help me how to get the user input from jsp to servlet page(Context).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: ServletContextListener is used to get notifications when web app is started or destroyed. Why do you want to pass something from JSP to ServletContext?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar sir i have set a timer in ServletContextListener the value of which i need to set by the user to execute operation on the time provided by the user

Comment: I guess you misunderstood your functional requirement. Please post it and you may receive better and more accurate guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You just cant pass any data to those methods from JSP as they are lifecycle method of the web application. `contextInitialized` fire way before you see the jsp.

`ServletContextListener` is used to initialize and cleaning up of resources used in application.
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404654/appropriate-use-of-a-servletcontextlistener-in-java-apache-tomcat-web-applicat) post for appropriate use of ServletContextListener.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the timer's timeout from user's request, you'll have to:

- put the timer into ServletContext, so other components (such as servlet or jsp) can access it. Add this into your listener's contextInitialized `event.getServletContext().setAttribute("timer",timer);`
- access your timer from servlet using `getServletContext().getAttribute("timer")`
- you access your timer even from JSP, it will be stored in `application` scope